# Find Duplicated Elements in a List of Integer without using distinct() method

Tags: java, performance, java-8, java-stream

Recently, I've been asked this question during an **Interview** :

> How to find the Duplicate Elements in a `List` of `Integer` without
> using java Stream's `distinct()` method ?

This should be done by Java's Stream API, but should not use `distinct()` method.

*Stub-code:*

```
List<Integer> listOfInt = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Use `groupingBy` to make a `Map<Integer, Integer>`, where the key is the integer in the stream and the value is the count.

Comment: That’s a strange question. It implies that there was a straight-forward way to find duplicates *with* the `distinct()` method.

Comment: @Holger I was thinking about that too.  Makes you wonder if the interviewers know what their talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using frequency collectors. Have not looked at optimization , but this will not use distinct

```java
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toSet;
import java.util.Collections;

public class DetectDuplicates{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      List<Integer> companyIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      companyIds.add(1);
      companyIds.add(1);
      companyIds.add(2);
      companyIds.add(3);
      companyIds.add(3);
      Set<Integer> duplicateCompanies = companyIds
                .stream()
                .filter(company -> Collections.frequency(companyIds, company) > 1)
                .collect(toSet());
      System.out.println("Duplicate companies " + duplicateCompanies);
    }
}
```

This will print

```
Duplicate companies [1, 3]
```

Comment: That’s very inefficient. For every element of the list, it will run through the entire list to count the occurrences, leading to a quadratic time complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Method  `distinct()` will not allow you *"to find duplicated elements"*. You'll even never know if there were any duplicates in the source by using `distinct()` method alone. As its name suggests, it will give you unique elements and nothing more.

One of the ways to filter out duplicated elements from the source list is by generating an intermediate `Map<Integer,Boolean>` where the *key* would be the element itself and the *value* would denote whether a particular *key* has duplicates in the source list.

That can be done by using a built-in collector [`toMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)):

```
List<Integer> duplicates = sourceList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Function.identity(),  // the key - an element itself
        next -> false,        // the value of `false` - the element isn't proved yet to be a duplicate because it has been encountered for the first time
        (left, right) -> true // the value of `true` - the element is a duplicate
    ))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .filter(Map.Entry::getValue)
    .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this by grouping by count and using `collectingAndThen` to make it a single pass (instead of using more than 1 stream)

```java
List<Integer> numbers = List.of(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4);
Set<Integer> duplicates = numbers.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()), frequencyMap -> {
            frequencyMap.values().removeIf(k -> k < 2);
            return frequencyMap.keySet();
        }));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a third-party library, you could create a `Bag` using [Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections), and use the `selectDuplicates` method on `Bag` to find the duplicates. First, you would need to convert a JDK `List` to a `Bag` using the `list.stream().collect(Collectors2.toBag())`. This would satisfy the requirement to use the Java Streams API.

```
@Test
public void selectDuplicates()
{
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(List.of(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4));
    Set<Integer> duplicates = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors2.toBag()).selectDuplicates().toSet();
    Set<Integer> expected = Set.of(2, 3, 4);
    Assertions.assertEquals(expected, duplicates);
}
```

If you can't use a third-party library, then you can use the `groupingBy` and `counting` `Collectors` in the JDK.

```
@Test
public void selectDuplicatesJDK()
{
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(List.of(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4));
    Map<Integer, Long> counts = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i, Collectors.counting()));
    counts.values().removeIf(count -> count < 2L);
    Set<Integer> duplicates = counts.keySet();
    Set<Integer> expected = Set.of(2, 3, 4);
    Assertions.assertEquals(expected, duplicates);
}
```

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections